# JSF: Cancel datatable row edit after data submission in Primefaces

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

I'm developing a web-app in JSF 2.1 + Primefaces 5.1. I have a datatable with editable rows. I catch the `rowEdit` event and call a DB procedure to do some validations of the new data and update the record when the user clicks the "check" button. But there's a problem: the datatable row in the GUI is updated whether the validations succeed or fail. I want the changes in the row data to be reversed to their previous state if the validations done in the DB procedure fail. How can I do that?

```html
<p:dataTable id="users_table_id" var="user" value="#{usersBean.users}" rowKey="#{user.id}" paginator="true"
            paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
               rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15" emptyMessage="#{msgs.no_records}" sortBy="#{user.id}" sortOrder="ascending" rows="15" editable="true">
            <f:facet name="header">
                #{msgs.users}               
            </f:facet>
            <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{usersBean.onRowEdit}"/>
            <p:ajax event="rowEditInit" listener="#{usersBean.onRowEditInit}"/>
            <p:column headerText="#{msgs.id}" sortBy="#{user.id}" styleClass="centered-column">
                #{user.id}
            </p:column>          
            <p:column headerText="#{msgs.description}" sortBy="#{user.description}" styleClass="centered-column">
                <p:cellEditor>
                    <f:facet name="output">#{user.description}</f:facet>
                    <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText value="#{user.description}" styleClass="editable-cell"/></f:facet>
                </p:cellEditor>
            </p:column> 
            ...
            <p:column styleClass="datatable-row-editor">
                <p:rowEditor/>
            </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

```java
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class UsersBean implements Serializable {

    private List<DtoUser> users;

    public void onRowEdit(RowEditEvent event) {
        logger.entry();
        DtoUser dtoUser = (DtoUser)event.getObject();
        this.updateUser(dtoUser);
        logger.exit();
    }

    public void updateUser(DtoUser dtoUser) { 
        try {
            logger.entry(dtoUser);
            DtoBoUsers dtoBoUsers = dtoUser.toDtoBoUsers();
            DtoTypeGenericResponse genericResponse = usersService.updateUser(dtoBoUsers);
            if (genericResponse.isError()) {
                // error in user update
            } else {
                // update successful
            }
            logger.exit(dtoUser);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e.fillInStackTrace()));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You do validation in the application layer, so as far as JSF is concerned, there are no errors and the new values are used. So if you want to keep the editor open, create a custom validator

Comment: @Kukeltje I've created the custom validator but I still have problems: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30033853/invalidate-primefacess-datatable-row-on-row-edition